# Firebase Java Server User Authorization

Tags: java, server, firebase

I'm creating an IoT java project where I need to authorize with user credentials instead of a 'Service Account'.  Is this possible with the firebase-server-sdk-3.0.0 project?

Comment: Will you be using the JVM client? https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/

Comment: I am using the jvm client with a Service Account.  I would like to use an individual's credentials

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37080175/190908